# How to move the text to the left and right in the same line?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I am writing my thesis, and trying to move some text to left/center/right in the same line. For example, I want to put Thesis reviewers on the left, Examination Committee in the right, how do I do that?

My code is

```
\begin{small}

\begin{center}
\textit{Examination Committee}
\\ \vspace{4pt} Prof.
\\ \vspace{4pt} Prof.
\\ \vspace{4pt} Prof.
\end{center}
\begin{center}
 \textit{Thesis reviewers}
\\ \vspace{4pt} Prof.
\\ \vspace{4pt} Prof.
\end{center}

\end{small}
```

My example as below[image]

Comment: Text left \hfill text right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, one `tabularx` with three columns, the first and last ones are left-aligned to occupy their natural widths and the middle one is an `X` column-type to swallow the remaining horizontal space.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begingroup
  \small
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lXl@{}}
    \textit{External Reviewers}  & & \textit{Examination Commitee} \\
    Prof.\@ John Doe             & & Prof.\@ Dr.\@ Jane Doe        \\
    Prof.\@ Dr.\@ Max Mustermann & & Prof.\@ Lieschen M\"uller     \\
                                 & & Prof.\@ Nomen Nescio
  \end{tabularx}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

The two blocks could be set in a `tabular` with increased row heights. Then the lines in a block can be left aligned, but the right block can be moved to the right:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\vspace{2em}

\begingroup
  \small
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    \itshape External Reviewers\\
    Prof.\@ John Doe\\
    Prof.\@ Dr.\@ Max Mustermann\\
  \end{tabular}\hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    \itshape Examination Commitee\\
    Prof.\@ Dr.\@ Jane Doe\\
    Prof.\@ Lieschen M\"uller\\
    Prof.\@ Nomen Nescio\\
  \end{tabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]